# 'TINYMCE_SCRIPT_SRC' was not found in '@tinymce/tinymce-angular' package

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5

I have an Angular 8 project. I am trying to implement tinymce in my project.

So I went through these 2 documentation links which I found useful: [Link1](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/angular-pm/)  [Link2](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce-angular#readme)

Mentioned in the above Link2 document, as I am on Angular 8 so I am using tinymce 3.x
[image]

So I started to follow the installation & configuration steps given in Link1.

But now facing an issue in which `TINYMCE_SCRIPT_SRC` is not found in '@tinymce/tinymce-angular'.

[image]

I followed all the instructions as mentioned in the document:
[image]

[image]

[image]

But I am still facing the issue. What can be the problem?

Kindly help. Thanks.